# Show weekday in laravel with carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I try to get date with carbon I also need to get weekday of it.

Explanation:

I have this in my controller `$arrivaltime = Carbon::now()->addWeekdays(5);` and this in my view `Arrival: {{ $arrivaltime->format('d m, Y')}}` which will return like this:

`Arrival: 19 10, 2017`

But what I want is like this:

`Arrival: Thursday 19 10, 2017`

How do I get that?

thanks.

Comment: Try: `$arrivaltime->format('l d m, Y')`

Comment: @CarlGroner please make in answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply include the full day name in the format string:

```
$arrivaltime->format('l d m, Y')
```